# What's the Facebook/AirBnb app design effect called?

Tags: mobile, user-experience

I want to read about that effect you see on pages like Facebook or Airbnb when you open the page and the browser shows you the low fidelity design of page while the actual data loads - so you'll see grey box instead in the place where pictures of the users will be, grey rectangles instead of the text content etc. I've been searching for hours but cannot find anything useful, anyone knows the name of this UX practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is referred to as loading dummy content. There wasn't much info when I searched for it, but I do know that the basic principle is first [load a gray background for images](http://embed.ly/docs/tutorials/background) and [dummy block font](http://blokkfont.com/) then wait for your content to render.